# Lua LocalScript: Part won't get change when i click it

Tags: lua, roblox

So I'm trying to make an locked area part where if you click it with enough money it would let the player who purchased enter it and change the part's properties

I actually used `parent:Destroy()`, `parent` is a variable containing the script's parent aka the part itself. But because it didn't work, I tried using `parent.CanCollide = 0` instead of `:Destroy`. Of course, again it didn't do anything, and no output. Here's the code

```
local parent = script.Parent

parent.ClickDetector.Mouseclick:connect(function(player)
    local money = player.leaderstats.money

    if money.Value >= 500 then
        money.Value -= 500
        parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Bright Green")
        parent.CanCollide = 0
    else
        parent.Transparency -= 0.5
        parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Maroon")
        wait(0.5)
        parent.Transparency += 0.5
        parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Crimson")
    end
end)
```

Comment: Instead of `part.CanCollide=0`, try `part.CanCollide=false`.

Comment: i dont think it willcwork at all. because when i ran the code above, it didnt output anything. so my code mustve only work with server sided script. but here im just trying to get help on how to turn it into a client sided script. oh yeah and thx for that. all of these werent meant to hurt anyone so sorry if i accidently offended you. oh yeah, even if i did do that, it wouldnt do anything. normally it would output something. so yeah i could tell that your answer wont work.

Comment: I also recommend using a boolean as documented: https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BasePart#CanCollide
Especially because it explicitly says here that 0 is considered true: https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/luau/booleans
Just to make sure, you know that the code run, e.g.: the object became Bright Green? Or via print check?

Comment: object becomes green and walk throughable

Comment: and no it wont work unless i made it server sided which i dont like

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you should probably do `MouseClick` not `Mouseclick`

here;

when you delete the `parent` of the script the script stops working and gets disabled unless it's in ReplicatedFirst or something not really that good in replicating

check your script if it's disabled or not

check if your script is accessible to the clients like can they see it?

you also shouldn't use a localscript for this

tell me if it works

Comment: I dont think I know how to make a server sided code that acts like a local script. could you like, rewrite the code for me. oh yeah its not using :Destroy() anymore. its using the transparency properties function